# Timeout error when downloading large files with URL

Tags: json, r, database, web-scraping, timeout

when I try and download the datasets within the for loop I always get this error Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The operation timed out'
I have tried changing the timeout to different values 100,200,500,1000, but it doesn't seem to be changing as the error occurs after the same amount of time regardless of what value I set.

```
## Get catalog and select for dataset ids, also filtered out data sets that don't contain key words
catalog<-tbl_df(read.csv2("https://datasource.kapsarc.org/explore/download/"))
select(catalog,datasetid,country,data.classification,title,theme,keyword)%>%
filter(grepl("Demo|Econo|Trade|Industry|Policies|Residential",theme))%>%
  select(datasetid)->datasets

data_kapsarc<-list()
base_url<-"https://datasource.kapsarc.org/api/v2/catalog/datasets/population-by-sex-and-age-group/exports/json?rows=-1&start=0&pretty=true&timezone=UTC"

options(timeout=1000)

##download data sets and store in  list of dataframes
for (i in 1:length(datasets$datasetid)){
  try({
    url<-gsub("population-by-sex-and-age-group",datasets[i,1]$datasetid,base_url)
    temp <- tempfile()
    download.file(url,temp,mode='wb')
    data_kapsarc[[i]]<-fromJSON(temp)
    unlink(temp)
  },silent=TRUE)


}
```

Comment: Hey there I'm having this issue as well. Have you found any solutions?